# Build short cypher starting from a number and a password

Tags: php, encryption

I have to build 50,000 codes starting from an incremental number (1 to 50000) and a secret password. I have to do it in php and the final code must be 8 or 12 characters long and contain only uppercase letters (A-Z) and numbers (0-9).

The final codes must be **decryptable** with the password...

I'm trying with openssl_encrypt but I can not find a way to make "short" the final code.

```
$longCode = openssl_encrypt($number, $method, ENC_KEY, true, $iv);
$shortCode = .....
```

Some ideas?

Comment: As you speak about a 'password', I assume you want to be able to decrypt again, right? You're not looking for a cryptographic hashing function? This might be better in place at security.stackexchange.

Comment: First I thought about suggesting the [Vigenènere cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), but seeing as your plaintext (numbers from 1 to 50k) is so limited (and ordered, at that) it turns into a weak caeser cypher.. Can you post some more requirements?

Comment: Joost is right I want to be able to decrypt the code back.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to use a cipher method that has a block size of 8 bytes, e.g. "rc2-cbc".

```
$nr = 1234;
$key = 'secretkey';
$method = 'rc2-cbc';

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));

$code = openssl_encrypt($nr, $method, $key, true, $iv);
```

The second step is casting the resulting string into your alphabet; because your alphabet size is only 36, the closest and "easy" conversion is base32; this gives (after stripping away the optional padding) a string of exactly 13 characters.

Theoretically you can convert 4 bytes into 6 characters of base36:

```
log(36) / log(2) ~ 5.17 bits, saves 1 bit after 6 blocks

6 x 5.17 ~ 31.02, 6 blocks fits inside 32 bits (unsigned long)

32 bits = 4 bytes -> 6 characters
```

**Faulty implementation**

The following code should do it - but doesn't (always) work!

```
$final = '';
foreach (str_split($code, 4) as $part) {
    $x = current(unpack('L', $part));
    $final .= strtoupper(base_convert($x, 10, 36));
}
```

Decoding would go like this:

```
$code2 = '';
foreach (str_split($final, 6) as $part) {
        $code2 .= pack('L', base_convert(strtolower($part), 36, 10));
}
```

Somehow the integer precision can't handle it or I'm doing something stupid; either way, it doesn't always work.

Comment: 13 characters... near to the solution... I have a must to stay into 12 characters.

Comment: @wildnove Managed to fit it into 12 characters :)

Comment: are you able to show me how to decrypt the code back into a number?

Comment: @wildnove I'm still proving the correctness on a piece of paper :)

Comment: @wildnove Unfortunately, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Comment: @wildnove I ran my code a few times with random IV; it's like 50/50 ... the problem is that it goes wrong when all 32 bits are used; annoying.

Comment: exactly, however I liked your answer

Comment: @wildnove Thanks, hope you can stretch to 13 characters :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
// generate random ID
    function generateRandomID ($len) {
        //To Pull Unique Random Values Out Of AlphaNumeric
        //removed number 0, capital o, number 1 and small L
        //Total: keys = 32, elements = 33
        $characters = array(
        "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","J","K","L","M",
        "N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
        "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");

        //make an "empty container" or array for our keys
        $keys = array();

        //first count of $keys is empty so "1", remaining count is 1-6 = total 7 times
        while(count($keys) < $len) {
                //"0" because we use this to FIND ARRAY KEYS which has a 0 value
                //"-1" because were only concerned of number of keys which is 32 not 33
                //count($characters) = 33
                $x = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
                if(!in_array($x, $keys)) {
                     $keys[] = $x;
                }
        }

        foreach($keys as $key){
             $random_chars .= $characters[$key];
        }
        return $random_chars;
    }
```

EDIT: Removed some letters and numbers for better user-friendly reading, see comments in code.

Comment: How is that even remotely close to being decryptable, when you have the password?

Comment: As far I read the question, user needs a function for generating a 50000 random codes, what decryption you mean?

Comment: He's generating codes based on an integer and a secret password. Don't you think he'd want to be able to decrypt the code with the secret password? Like in a shared key crypto protocol? Nowhere did he mention the word 'random'.

Comment: True, but isn't that an inherit function of a 'secret password'?